# C# help ExecuteNonquery

Tags: c#

I really don't know why I'm getting this message

> ExecuteNonQuery: CommandText property has not been initialized

I have no erros at all in my code and it looks good when I look at it. I've been looking at the web for solutions but can't find any. This is my code. Any help much appreciated.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=VALONS;Initial Catalog=gym;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand cmd;
    public NewMem()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void NewMem_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into member(SocialSecurity, Name, City, Street, Zipcode, Email, Phone) values ('" + textSocialSecurity + "','" + textName + "','" + textCity + "','" + textStreet + "','" + textZipCode + "','" + textEmail + "','" + textPhone + "')" + conn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("You have successfully inserted values in Member");
            conn.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

        }
    }
```

Comment: You are aware of the security issue called sql injection your code has?

Comment: Maybe ", conn" instead of "+ conn"?

Comment: What happens when Mr O'Reilly types his name in? You need to use SqlParameters for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue might be related to datataype mismatch.
Try using parameters instead of directly values becuase of sql injection issue.

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into member(SocialSecurity, Name, City, Street, Zipcode, Email, Phone) values (:1,:2,:3,:4,:5,:6,:7)", conn);
cmd.parameters.clear();
cmd.parameters.Add("1", textSocialSecurity);
cmd.parameters.Add("2", textName);
...
cmd.parameters.Add("7", textPhone);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: `AddWithParameter()` instead of `Add()` and it is `cmd.Parameters`.

Comment: Add has been deprecated. Use AddWithValue

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to do this :

`cmd.CommandText = @"Insert into member(SocialSecurity, Name, City, Street, Zipcode, Email, Phone) values ('" + textSocialSecurity + "','" + textName + "','" + textCity + "','" + textStreet + "','" + textZipCode + "','" + textEmail + "','" + textPhone + "')";`

But you have serious problems. And you're open to sql injections.

Parameterize the query.

Answer (score -1):

Your command needs to be told what type it is. Stored procedure, command text etc. I cannot remember the method but that is the problem.

I would recommend that you do this in stages - open the connection, create a command object and set the connection property, set it's type and the execute the SQL text. I would also recommend using a stored procedure with parameters as that get's around the SQL injection issue.

Comment: I would find it very useful to know why my answer was down voted